# Sending commands to a list of TidTCPClients

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

My code creates several TidTCPClients and then adds references to them in a TThreadList.

I was hoping to send commands to all of them by then using

```
for I := 0 to (NumClients - 1) do
begin
  ClientList[I].IOHandler.WriteLn('Whatever');
end;
```

(that's obviously only a small part of the code).

However I'm getting two errors:
[DCC Error] Client.pas(261): E2149 Class does not have a default property
[DCC Error] Client.pas(262): E2233 Property 'IOHandler' inaccessible here

and after a brief read of [This](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_need_default_property_xml.html) I'm none the wiser about how to do this, but definitely beginning to think that I'm on the wrong track entirely.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See [doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThreadList) how to operate `TThreadList`. LockList and UnlockList plus how to address the objects in the list TidTCPClient(list[I]).IOHandler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThreadList) how to operate `TThreadList`. You also need to type cast the `TidTCPClient` objects in the list since it only contains untyped pointers.

```
var
  list: TList;
...
list := ClientList.LockList;
try
  for I := 0 to list.Count - 1 do
  begin
    TidTCPClient(list[I]).IOHandler.WriteLn('Whatever');
  end;
finally
  ClientList.UnlockList;
end;
```

Comment: +1 (Beat me to it. <g>) A better link to the docs might be the [TThreadList code sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/TThreadList_%28Delphi%29) instead, though.

Comment: Thanks, I just typed exactly that out based on your comment!